# Ubuntu 14.04 and Dell Latitude E5540 Multiple Monitors not working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have the following configuration:

```
lspci | grep VGA  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

I docked my laptop and I have two lcd monitors connected via DVI. Now i'm able to see only one monitor in my displays.

Other monitor replicates my first monitor. So I have Laptop screen and one monitor working. I want 2nd monitor also to be detected in my displays so that i could extend it.

Is there any one with similar problem?

I tried to install the nvidia drivers but no help.

Comment: Have you tried 13.10? or 12.04? Did it worked?

Comment: Yes..it did work..